# How to decrease row height. (TableLayout>TableRow)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tablelayout

The height of the rows in this `TableLayout` is too much, higher than needed to allow for the text. 
I've played with a number of different values, but can't get it right. 
[According to the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html), the default value for children of a `TableLayout` is `wrap_content`, 
but the row height appears to be more than that. 
Also it says that the value of the width is always `wrap_content`, 
so there's no point in setting that.
By "children" does that mean only the direct children (TableRow in this case), 
or all underneath (TextView in this case)?

How do I decrease the row height?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:shrinkColumns="*"
    android:stretchColumns="*"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp">

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewNameLabel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="sans"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:text="@string/name_string"
        android:gravity="start">
    </TextView>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:typeface="sans"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:text="Michael Foucalt"
        android:gravity="start">
    </TextView>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewTitleLabel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="sans"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:text="@string/title_string"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:padding="10dp">
    </TextView>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:typeface="sans"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:text="Philosopher"
        android:gravity="start">
    </TextView>
</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewPhoneLabel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="sans"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:text="@string/phone_string"
        android:gravity="start">
    </TextView>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewPhone"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:typeface="sans"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:text="555.111.2222"
        android:gravity="start">
    </TextView>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewFaxLabel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="sans"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:text="@string/fax_string"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:padding="10dp">
    </TextView>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewFax"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:typeface="sans"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:text="555.123.4567"
        android:gravity="start">
    </TextView>
</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewAddressLabel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="sans"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:text="@string/address_string"
        android:gravity="start">
    </TextView>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewAddress"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:typeface="sans"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:text="555 Champs Elysses"
        android:gravity="start">
    </TextView>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewCityLabel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="sans"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:text="@string/city_string"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:padding="10dp">
    </TextView>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewCity"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:typeface="sans"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:text="Paris"
        android:gravity="start">
    </TextView>
</TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Here are images showing the current display and the desired display:

[image: Current]

[image: Desired]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please remove:

```
android:layout_weight="1"
```

from the TableRow elements. It will cause the rows to be equally stretched along the length of the screen.

**EDIT**
The children in this instance would both be the TableRow and TextView. That's why doing something like this would be legal:

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow1">

    <TextView
         android:id="@+id/textViewNameLabel"
         android:gravity="start"
         android:text="@string/name_string"
         android:textSize="18sp"
         android:textStyle="bold"
         android:typeface="sans" />

         .
         .
         .

    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

They would all automatically be assigned wrap_content for their width and height attributes by wrapping in a TableLayout

**EDIT 2:**
Remove from all TextView components:

```
android:padding="10dp"
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This has no effect.

Comment: Can you please add the rest of the xml to your question?

Comment: I did post the entire file. There is a display problem in that the <TableLayout> tag is not showing. If you were to edit the question, I think you could see it.

Comment: Sent edit for the code formatting.
You say the row is just higher than needed. What it is you see right now and what do you expect to see?

Comment: I've added images showing the current display and the desired display.